# Turtles changing more then one patch netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

I am new to programming and using netlogo so this question is probably too simple.
I am creating a model in which households decide their farming area each year (changing the location every year). I need to make them change the type of vegetation of n patches, according to the size they decided previously.
I know primitives like in-radius, neighbor and neighbor4 but all of them don't give me the freedom to change the exact number I want. For example, if the farming area is 3 hectares, how can i make one household change 3 patches vegetation type? How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
n-of 3 neighbors
```

That would give you three random patches among the patche's neighbors, which may or may not be what you want, but your question isn't precise enough to say...

Let us know if that works for you. If not, give us a bit more detail.

Comment: Heeey, It does work !!!! thank you soooo much :) 
But sometimes I need more then 8 patch, should I use in radius?


Another doubt, I need to make the households to move to a forest area, but I wanted them to choose a patch with the number of forest neighbors that they need to deforest, is there any way I can put this in the code?

Comment: You can use `n-of` with `in-radius` as well if you want to, e.g.: `n-of 10 patches in-radius 5`. As for your other question, I think it warrants opening a separate question.

Comment: Thaaaanks! will do that :)